# Is it possible to reference a single path and method in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: openapi

Suppose I have an OpenAPI 3 document describing API `Foo` as follows:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: '1'
  title: Foo
paths:
 /foo:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        description: A Foo
  post:
    responses:
      201:
        description: Foo created
```

In another OpenAPI document for API `Bar`, I would like to reference *only* the `GET /foo` operation from API `Foo`. The OpenAPI docs [talk a little about referencing a whole path](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/). However, if I do the following:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: '1'
  title: Bar
paths:
 /foo:
  $ref: 'foo.yaml#/paths/~1foo'
```

I naturally get both the `GET` and the `POST` in API `Bar`, since only the path is referenced, not the method.

I tried this:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: '1'
  title: Bar
paths:
 /foo:
   get:
     $ref: 'foo.yaml#/paths/~1foo/get'
```

But this gives errors like `should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: $ref` and `should have required property 'responses' missingProperty: responses` in various tools, so it doesn't seem to be supported.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I should note that the real request is much more complicated, hence the desire to de-duplicate. If possible I would like to avoid filling in many child objects of `get` with individual `$ref`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenAPI doesn't have a way to `$ref` an individual operation (`get`/`post`/etc.), you can only `$ref` an entire path.

You can propose syntax enhancements in the OpenAPI Specification repository:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues